# Changing images in phaser preload

Tags: phaser-framework

So when I'm adding an image in the preload function of phaser like this:

```
function preload() {  
    this.load.image('platform', 'images/platform.png', 10, 15);  
}
```

and then later on I am changing the width and height, or I want to update my image to a newer image, it doesn't seem to update this. When I test my game its still the old image with the original width and height.

```
function preload() {  
    this.load.image('platform', 'images/platform.png', 15, 20);  
}
```

the new code with another image with the same name

Comment: What are the third and fourth arguments? The API says that you should provide three arguments: image key, URL and (optionally) a bool which says whether to overwrite a possibly existing image in the cache with the same key.

Comment: i am just replacing the old code by the new code, or is this bad practice? i am new to phaser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load a new image with the same key you should do:
First call:

```
this.load.image('platform', 'images/image.png');
```

Second call (with 'true' as third parameter):

```
this.load.image('platform', 'images/new.png', true);
```

IMHO, you should reconsider this choice and load the two images with two separate keys, and then use the one or the other depending on your needs.

Comment: Hamdi, thx for your answer. This sort of solves my problem, but the thing is that i don't want to use the first platform image anymore. Can't i get rid off it all together just by replacing the code?

Comment: yes ;) that's what i did initially and that is the whole problem. he keeps showing the old image

Comment: `var game = new Phaser.Game(360, 640, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

    function preload() {
        this.load.image('platform', 'images/platform.png', 10, 15)
    }`

that's it, and then i change for example to  'images/platform.png', 15, 20.

But nothing changes

Comment: Because it is the same file `platform.png`. Did you try doing it with another file, and with `true` as third parameter. This is what I gave in my answer: `this.load.image('platform', 'images/new.png', true);`. Please not the **new.png** and the **true** parameter

Comment: well i guess its the only solution. but its good enough for me :) thx alot